# Change CSS of the link in my asp:menu

Tags: asp.net, html, css

[image: My Menu]

I have changed my asp.net menu style. But I can't change the < a href > style. Look in the image above, the size of the link does not get all the size of the < td > element.

Is there a way to do that?

Here is my CSS

```
.menuItem
{
    height: 50px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    width: 220px;
}

.menuItem a
{
    width:220px;
    height:50px;
}
```

And my HTML

```
<table class="menuItem MnuMain_4" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;">
         <a class="MnuMain_1 menuItem MnuMain_3" style="border-style:none;font-            size:1em;" target="main" href="Pages/Cadastro/CadPrograma.aspx">
         <img style="border-style:none;vertical-align:middle;" alt="" src="Imagens/Menu/btn-programa.png">
&nbsp;&nbsp;IDs
         </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Post some html/css from your page to give us a better understanding

Comment: posted, it is a simple link inside a <td> tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding display:block to the anchor's css.

```
.menuItem a
{
    display:block;
    width:220px;
    height:50px;
}
```